# I lost apturl accidentally! any way to regain it?

Tags: apturl

I accidentally uninstalled `aptURL` from my PC. I use Ubuntu 14.04. I can't install any apps. If anyone know the steps to regain it, please help!I can't find a way to re-install `aptURL`.

Comment: I've answered you, refresh your browser and check it

Answer (score 1):

You can easily restore it from a terminal window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) using the command

```
sudo apt-get install apturl
```

I may quote the manpage of **apturl** (command `man apturl`):

> **apturl** is a simple graphical application that takes an URL
>   (following the apt-protocol) as a command line option, parses it and
>   carries out the operations that the URL describes (that is, it asks
>   the user if he wants the indicated packages to be installed and if the
>   answer is positive does so).

That means **apturl** is not needed to install packages directly, but just to resolve links like `apt:packagename` in websites to open the Software Center and install the linked package. Therefore you are still able to use command line tools like **apt-get** and probably even the Software Center to install packages.

Comment: but it shows,Package 'apturl' has no installation candidate.

Comment: then what to do?

Comment: Thats all then use it

Comment: use what , or do what?

Comment: Now you have apt url working again so you can now use it as before

Comment: the command you given aint working

Comment: its giving info about apturl-common

Comment: what is the output of this command `sudo apt-get install apturl` ? Edit your question and add the output there